# SQL (MS Access): For a given record, how to query top 5 values from a given set of fields?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have a table with a few dozen fields, 18 of which are fields with varying integer values. I'd like to pull the field names and corresponding values for the five fields with the greatest values for a given record. I'll use the below table as example where I'd like to query only the two greatest values for a given record.

```
Name, FigureA, FigureB, FigureC
John, 40,      73,      81
Luke, 35,      21,      65
```

I'd like to return the following for, say, John:

```
FigureB, 73
FigureC, 81
```

I've gotten this far:

```
sSQL = "Select t.* " & _
            "From (Select 'A' as [FigureA], FigureA " & _
                    "From Table) as t " & _
            "Union All " & _
           "Select t.* " & _
            "From (Select 'B' as [FigureB], FigureB " & _
                    "From Table) as t " & _
            "Union All " & _
           "Select t.* " & _
            "From (Select 'C' as [FigureC], FigureC " & _
                    "From Table) as t"
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access, this is probably simplest with `union all`:

```
select top (5) *
from (select t.*
      from (select top (1) "field1" as colname, max(field1) as max_val
            from t
           ) as t
      union all
      select t.*
      from (select top (1) "field2" as colname, max(field2)
            from t
           ) as t
      union all
      . . . 
     ) as t
order by max_val desc;
```

Some versions of MS Access don't support `union all` in the `from` clause.  That component might require a view.

Comment: So where am I indicating that I only want the 5 greatest values out of all of those results that I'm unioning?

Comment: @MichaelSmith . . . You can use a subquery and `top (5)` in the outer query.

Comment: I've posted my initial attempt in the post above. Where am I going wrong? At the moment, I'm not concerned with the top 5. Just wanting to return all of the results to check that it's working correctly.